# Gatling: exclude preparation request from reports

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

Here is my test scenario on Gatling:

```
val createTemplatesScenario = scenario("Template creation")
  .feed(userFeeder)
  .exec(doLogin) // populates access token in the session
  .exec(doListProviders)
  .exec(doCreateTemplate)
    ...
  .exec(doDeleteTemplate)
```

And I want to exclude **Login** request from reports because sometimes it can take too much time on our system and affects all the metrics:

[image: Gatling report]

Is there a way to "prepare" test scenario so that only necessary actions will be taken into account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [groups of requests](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2/general/scenario/#groups-definition).

Add all your requests except **Login** to a group.

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2/general/reports/):

> If your scenario contains groups, this panel becomes a tree : each group is a non leaf node, and each request is a descendant leaf of a group. Group timings are by default the cumulated response times of all elements inside the group. Group duration can be displayed instead of group cumulated response time by editing the gatling.conf file.

The **Global Information** node should still be affected by **Login** request, but the node for your group of all other requests should contain unaffected aggregate results.

Comment: This is probably the only option. Thank you!